# Minimal time to notify all nodes of network

Tags: algorithm, graph

Problem: Input is undirected graph with weights on edges which represents network of computers where weights of edges mean minimal time required to send message between two computers. We pick one vertex of this graph and send a message to connected vertices. When vertex receives message it will resend it to neighbors only once. Need to find minimal time to notify every vertex in the graph.

I have implemented brute-force algorithm to sole this, but it is too slow (N^2). Firstly I thought that this could be solved as weight of minimal spanning tree, but it needs something over it.

I think there is some existing algorithm for this problem...

Comment: Sounds like the traveling salesman problem...https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Yes, sounds like. But this algorithm looks for circular path in the graph and doesn't assume that there is may be more than one 'salesman' coming from every city that receives new message.

Answer (score 0):

A modification of [dijkstras algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) should do for this purpose. But instead of searching for the shortest path to a specific node, the algorithm terminates once all nodes have been visited. After completion of the above, the problem reduces to extracting the node with the maximum distance from the source-node from the table that was built during traversing the graph.

```
longest_path(node):
    # dijkstras algo
    path_len = map()
    queue = priority_queue()  # priority-queue sorted by distance to source-node
    visited = set() 

    path_len[node] = 0
    queue.put(node)       

    while queue not empty
        n = queue.pop()

        if n in visited
            continue

        for neighbor in n.neighbors()
            dist = path_len[n] + n.edge_length(neighbor)
            if neighbor not in path_len or path_len[neighbor] > dist
                queue.offer(neighbor)
                path_len[neighbor] = dist

         visited.add(n)

     # find the node with the maximum distance to the source-node
     max = -1
     res = NULL
     for n in path_len.keys()
         if path_len[n] > max
             max = path_len[n]
             res = n

     return res
```

The above algorithm works in `O(|E| + |V| log |V|)` worst case.

Comment: Does your complexity estimation for this algorithms include complexity of operations on maps, sets, and priority queues that you use here?

Comment: @MishKotelkov sure. It's just the complexity of dijkstras algorithm. Using the standard complexities for those datastructures. You can look it up in the wikipedia-article I provided a link to in my answer